# Display WooCommerce edit-account Form Validation Errors Under Input Fields

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I am working on customizing the WooCommerce edit-account page on my WordPress website. I've encountered a challenge: I want the validation errors to display directly beneath their respective input fields, rather than in a global notice box.

[image: what i want to achieve.]

my code for edit-account-form:

```
  <div id="user-info-form-profile">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>
        <form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account m-0" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' ); ?> >

          <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

          <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
            <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
                            <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
                        </span>
          </p>

          <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
            <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
                            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
                        </span>
          </p>
          <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

          <!--                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">-->
          <!--                        <label for="password_current">--><?php //esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?><!--</label>-->
          <!--                        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />-->
          <!--                    </p>-->
          <!--                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">-->
          <!--                        <label for="password_1">--><?php //esc_html_e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?><!--</label>-->
          <!--                        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />-->
          <!--                    </p>-->
          <!--                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">-->
          <!--                        <label for="password_2">--><?php //esc_html_e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?><!--</label>-->
          <!--                        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />-->
          <!--                    </p>-->


          <p>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button-w-border mx-0 px-0 mt-1 mb-0 pb-0 button<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
          </p>

          <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
        </form>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: save_account_details pushes all errors in wc_add_notice() https://hooks.wbcomdesigns.com/reference/classes/wc_form_handler/save_account_details/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to pass error to your field.  https://prnt.sc/FogRd1HM4QRG

First copy the template into your theme to prevent overwrite when you update woocommerce - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Then in your form for each reqired field add div with ID for example first_name_error.

The example is just for the first name but you should have no problem to replicate it for each other field.

```
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    <div id="first_name_error" class="error-message"></div>
</p>
```

Then add the following function in your functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', 'pass_error_for_required_fields', 99, 2);

function pass_error_for_required_fields(&$errors, &$user) {
    $required_fields = array(
            'account_first_name'   => __( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ),
            'account_last_name'    => __( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ),
            'account_display_name' => __( 'Display name', 'woocommerce' ),
            'account_email'        => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    if (empty($user->first_name)) {
        $error_message = sprintf(__( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ),$required_fields['account_first_name']);
        echo '<script>var firstNameError = "'.esc_js($error_message).'";</script>';
    }
}
```

Then create js file or use one you have already where you wait for the error to pass it to the field.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(function () {
      $(document).ready(function($) {
        // Display the error message under the input field
        if (typeof firstNameError !== 'undefined' && firstNameError) {
            $('#first_name_error').html(firstNameError);
        }
      });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

To exclude some notices we dont want showing we need to copy template error.php from notices to our theme.
Then inside we need to change it like this

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
    <?php foreach ($notices as $notice) : 
        // Check if the notice should be excluded by ID
        if ($notice['data']['id'] === 'account_first_name') {
            continue; // Skip this notice
        }
    ?>
        <li<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr($notice); ?>>
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice($notice['notice']); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you!! works like a charm.

Comment: but it doesn't remove woocommerce default message from top of the page.

Comment: Hide em with css ?

Comment: I have added a way to change your notices.

Comment: ur absolutely legendary! thank you man